# What is the variable for the current cell in Excel?

Tags: excel, cell

What is the variable for the current cell? I have this:

```
=PRODUCT(B3,B45)
```

And I want the B3 to be the current cell. The problem right now is that when I drag the cell, it is kept as B3. I am sure this is hilariously easy to solve. This is the first time I use Excel.

Answer (score 5):

Use absolute reference.  $B$3 instead of B3.

Comment: @HumanKind - If Carl's answer solved your problem, please accept it (tick the green check mark next to it)